# DigitalOcean Droplet ssh to use a named key

Tags: ssh, hostname, digital-ocean, ssh-agent, ssh-keygen

It's been a while since I've done this and configured ssh keys.

I generated an ssh key with a different file name than id_rsa

I have a DigitalOcean Droplet where I placed a named ssh key pair on creation.

Then I created a `~/.ssh/config` on my **local machine**
where I configured my Host to use the proper identity file.

I made my hostname the IP of the droplet. I believe I can do that.

~/.ssh/config:

```
Host multipress
 Hostname XX.XXX.XXX.XXX
 User root
 IdentityFile  ~/.ssh/multipress
```

But when I try to connect it fails:

```
% ssh root@XX.XXX.XXX.XXX                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
   root@XX.XXX.XXX.XXX: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: You only need to add the public key in the digital ocean website interface and not the key pair. Please post the output of ssh -v root@XX.XXX.XXX.XXX to check the actual error message

Comment: @RaviKumarCH that's a helpful command. I did solve it. My host file on local needs IdentityFile!

Comment: from your ssh config file you only need to type `ssh multipress`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make this work.
I think the droplet just needed some time.